# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio not working after installing .Net Framework 4

Tags: installation, uninstall, .net-framework, sql-management-studio

Yesterday I installed .Net Framework 4 as it was required by Liquid XML Studio, but just after installing it, My SQL Server Management Studio stopped working. As soon as open the IDE I get

package microsoft sql management studio package failed to load

I tried pretty much all the solution posted on the internet but could not get it working, today when I removed the .Net Framework 4, SQL server management studio started working again.

Then just to test, I installed the .Net Framework 4 back ... and I started getting the same problem in management studio.

I want both on my machine ! how can i do it ?

PS : OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it was looking for the following registry key and not finding it.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools
```

You might have a look at more about [Solution for “Package ‘Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package’ failed to load”](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2012/01/04/solution-for-package-microsoft-sql-management-studio-package-failed-to-load/)

Hope this helps